# Generating base64 encoded md5 in C# and Python

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to convert a python code  to C# language while converting i have partially achieved my target by using just a simple string for e.g  "abc" in both languages and generating same encoded string  but i am stuck with json object here is the python code .

**Python**

```
import base64 , hashlib , hmac , json , httplib , socket , re , email,ssl,os
from time import strptime , mktime , timezone , time , gmtime , strftime , daylight



h=hashlib.new ('md5')
h.update(json.dumps({"username":"sym","password":"123"}))
pprint.pprint(h.digest())

pprint.pprint(base64 . b64encode(h.digest()))
```

**C#**

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Security;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;



 public partial class Main : Form
    {


    static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
        {

        Credentials cred = new Credentials();
                cred.username = "sym";
                cred.password = "123";
                string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cred);
byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output));
 string s  = Convert.ToBase64String(data);
return s ;




     }
}
```

Comment: You say you have partly achieved a solution. What part haven't you achieved? What isn't working? Please explain, it makes life easier for many people that potentially can answer.

Comment: i have generated the same base64 encoded string while using justa simple string in both languages . now explained thanks for pointing it out

Comment: So your actual question has nothing to do with any of this and the C# is actually irrelevant and a distraction to a MCVE. What you really need to know is how to serialize a string to JSON in Python?

Comment: Okay, you told us what did work... so what didn't work? Dictionaries are unordered, so if someone were to serialize them to json on different systems or with different languages, one would not expect their md5's to match.

Comment: did i convert the python code correctly in C# ??